# Handlebars.js Conditional Statement {{#if expression}} ... {{else}} ... {{/iif}} Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement Handlebars templating logic to show a "logged in" navbar (with a user's first name and profile image) if the user is authenticated or a "logged out" navbar if the user is not authenticated.

To do this, I am using the **handlebars.js** conditional statement:

```
{{#if login_status}}
     *logged in navbar html code*
{{else}}
     *logged out navbar html code*
{{/if}}
```

I am also using a helper **login_status.js** that returns **true** if authenticated and **false** is not authenticated, based on the existence of a user's ID.  My helper code looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(l) {
    if (l.data.root.id === undefined) {
        console.log('user is logged out');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('user is logged in: ', l.data.root.id);
        return true;
    }
};
```

However, this does not work, and it is always returning the {{else}} statement, meaning that the user is not authenticated.

Is there a better way of implementing this logic?  Is the helper code incorrect?  Is the handlebars {{#if}} expression incorrect?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Jesse

Comment: Hi,  Why can't you use "login_status" as a property of application controller instead of writing a helper? Can you please elaborate the reason for using a helper here.

Comment: @phkavitha Can you expand on how I might use "login_status" as a property of the application controller?  I wanted to only have one view per page rather than having a "logged in" view and a "logged out" view, as the main difference is usually just the navbar.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

phkavitha trying to say is that you can use (login_status function) as a property(getter) instead of a helper.

you can say:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile([your handlebars template]);
var html = template({
     ...
     get login_status() {
        return require('login_status.js')(l);
     }, 
     ...
})
```